# jqGrid custom interface filtering

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, postdata

I have a jqGrid which has an inbuilt filter and also i have my own interface for filtering grid data.. my interface is a jsp page loaded inside a dialog box.and i have a button in the navigator.. clicking on the button displays a dialog box with my jsp search inetrface loaded in it..and i dont know how to pass values from my search interface jsp dialogbox to the grid action class..i need an example clearly to explain how to use postData from my jsp-dialogbox to the initial gid action class..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand your question you will solve the problem by the usage of `postData` where you use methods (the functions as the properties of `postData` object). Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more details.